# How to use ARIMA in GARCH model

Tags: r, data-modeling, finance, arima, forecast

I have financial data and my goal is to be able to forecast. I ran an arima model and found that the best fit was arima(1,1,1) w/ drift. I want to use GARCH on the data set because it is the better model to use due to volatility and when I squared my residuals it did have the arch effect. But I know that GARCH takes in a 2 parameter arima and I am not sure how that translates from the 3 parameter arima I currently have.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(TSA)
library(forecast)
spnew<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/SPNEW.csv", header=T, 
sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
sfts1=ts(sp$`Adj Close`, 
freq=260,start=decimal_date(ymd("2009-01-02")))
arsf1=auto.arima(sfts1, trace=T)
```

I have the code to run for GARCH but am not sure what to input for the arima portion.

```
model1 <-  ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model="sGARCH",         
                                                 garchOrder=c(_,_)), 
                           mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(_,_)), 
                           distribution.model = "norm")        
mod2 <- ugarchfit(spec=model1, 
                          data=sfts1)
```

I left blanks for what I would need to input. I will play with the garch order once I know how to put in arima. If a better way to code the GARCH model is known please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, I refer to the model that you call 2 parameter arima as ARMA.
`rugarch::ugarchspec()` can treat ARMA(p, q) or ARFIMA(p, d, q) model as `mean.model`.
(NOTE: when d is integer, ARFIMA(p, d, q) is equivalent to ARIMA(p, d, q))

Here is my example;

```
p <- 1
q <- 1
# d <- 1    # if you want to fix d

model1 <-  ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model="sGARCH",         
                                            garchOrder=c(_, _)), 
                      mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(p, q),
                                        arfima = T),    # using arfima model
                      # fixed.pars=list(arfima = d),    # If you want to fix d
                      distribution.model = "norm"))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, @cuttlefish44

For my data, _auto.arima_ reports
ARIMA (0,0,0), (0,1,1) [12]

Can seasonality be taken into account?

Answer (score 0):

Seasonality can be incorporated by including `external.regressors =` in your `mean.model =` in `ugarchspec()`. The `fourier()`-function from the `forecast` package can help you find appropriate [fourier terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) that can be used as external regressors to represent seasonality.